# how to reset SharePoint 2013 list css class?

Tags: javascript, css, sharepoint-list, webpart-width

Preface:
I have a custom list in SharePoint 2013, and one of my text columns was too narrow causing it to use too much vertical space.  I used this link and followed the instructions to change the width:

https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/07512437-fecf-4257-bcc8-ba3c8e467554/how-to-increase-width-of-a-list-in-sharepoint-designer-2013

This worked somewhat but with weirdness.  So I could only adjust one column using this. And when Testing I made the column really wide, and now nothing I do reverts this back to the original state.

How can I reset the sharepoint css classes for this?  When I open my site in chrome and navigate to the column in question here is the code:

```
  <th scope="col" onmouseover="OnChildColumn(this)" style="max-width: 500px;" class="ms-vh2-nofilter" onmousedown="ListHeaderMenu_OnMouseDown(this);"><div sortable="FALSE" sortdisable="" filterdisable="" filterable="FALSE" filterdisablemessage="" name="Release_x0020_Details" ctxnum="0" displayname="Release Details" fieldtype="Note" resulttype="" sortfields="View={b5ba2cae-6051-4708-841d-19c988801156}&amp;SortField=Release_x0020_Details&amp;SortDir=Asc" class="ms-vh-div"><span title="This column type can't be sorted or filtered.">Release Details</span></div></th>
```

This has been driving me crazy so if anyone can help it would be amazing.  I'm not a javascript programmer so I'm not really sure if what I did caused this or how to go about fixing it.

Also an odd side effect of me trying to widen the column... in every browser except firefox the page gets so wide I need a scroll bar, but firefox is able to easily fit everything on a single page without a scroll bar.

Answer (score 0):

You have modified the code behind that renders the actual listview. Just try to create a new listview and you should be fine, deleting the old view.

Otherwise, fire up SharePoint Designer and navigate to the list and select the view where you made the change, and change the value back to default. (Whatever that was).